# How to reload server with changes via VS Code's liveshare shared terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

Helping a colleague out remotely with some coding using VS Code's LiveShare extension. I'd like to work on a file, save it, and have the server reload with the changes I have made.  Typically this would just hot-reload when I save the file, but it isn't because I am remotely editing via live-share session.  Also, even with a shared terminal I don't know of a way to restart the server as `ctrl-c` will exit out of the shared terminal.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably dependent on what type of code you are working on.
If it is js/css/html, you can launch the server with no cache and turn on the debugger, when you use the "Restart" function of the debugger, it will save the file and push the new version to the server.
I use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server.  It can be launched with no cache using the -c-1 option.